# Move the div for a specified distance before bounce

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div which move from up to bottom before bounce, i need to make the distance of the move bigger. My actual code is this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id=popup>
    <p>Please, choose what type of puzzle you'd like to play</p>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
       $(document).ready(function(){    
           $('#popup').show('bounce', { times:3 }, 300);
            });
```

i tried to add the distance argument but it doesn't do what i need.

```
       $(document).ready(function(){    
           $('#popup').show('bounce', { times:3 , distance: 200 }, 300);
        });//No effect what ever value i give to the `distance` argument.
```

You can see [the demo](http://spyrestudios.com/demos/cute-bar/) i am following. I need to move it to the center of the page (from top to center) before it gets bounced. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking is not really clear ... Still I think this should help :

Javascript

```
$('#popup').animate({
    top: (($(window).height()/2) - ($('#popup').outerHeight()/2)
)}, 2000, 'easeOutBounce');
```

Easing functions can be found [HERE](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js)

Comment: The popup gets placed in the middle of the viewport, then gets animated in order to make it move up to the top of the window, bouncing.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but what i want to perform is to animate the `div` from the top to the middle and then bounce it. So the user must see the animation from top to middle.

Comment: Oh yes, `easeOutBounce`. That's the key word i should be using :) Thanks a million :)

Comment: You are welcome `:)` ... By the way, show() signature is `.show( [duration] [, easing] [, callback] )`

Answer (score 1):

Setting `distance` and `direction` options should work:

```
$('#bounce').show("bounce", {
    times: 3,
        direction: "down",
        distance: $(window).height()/2
}, 300);
```

See the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/45RmZ/).